# How to filter duplicate values in Excel

Tags: excel

I wanted to know how to filter duplicate values in an excel in such a way that a value repeats only after all unique values are present before it.
For Eg

```
A
1
1
2
3
3
4
5
5
6
7
```

The output should be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
1
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A** starting in **A2**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)=1,1,"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Then filter on column **B** to display **1** only:

[image]